# avoid initializing variable to make code still working

Tags: java, variables

I made a guessing game where I first ask:
- how many players want to play the game
- assign all players
- start guessing the number in order
Winner is the player who guessed to correct number generated by using Random

Code works without issues but 1 thing concerns me;
I need to initialize guessingNumber variable first, which looks a bit odd because I need to type any number that I know won't be generated randomly, if I will only declare variable int guessingNumber I get an error here

```
} while (los != guessingNumber); - guessingNumber is underlined with error :
```

The local variable guessingNumber may not have been initialized

Do you know how to avoid initializing -1 digit and make code still working?

```
public class kopia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int los = rand.nextInt(11);
        int numberofPlayers;
        int guessingNumber= -1;

        Scanner scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println(" Type number of players :");
            while (!scan7.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, bad data");
                scan7.next();
            }
            numberofPlayers = scan7.nextInt();
        } while (numberofPlayers <= 0);

        String gracze[] = new String[numberofPlayers];
        int liczbaProbGraczy[] = new int[numberofPlayers];

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberofPlayers; i++) { // ++1

            System.out.println("Number of player " + i);
            gracze[i - 1] = scan.nextLine();
        }

        do {

            for (int j = 0; j < gracze.length; j++) {

                System.out.println(" Now guesssing " + gracze[j]);
                System.out.println("Guess number 0 do 10");
                while (!scan2.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Cannot recognize this number");
                    scan2.next();
                }
                guessingNumber = scan2.nextInt();

                liczbaProbGraczy[j]++;

                if (guessingNumber == los) {

                    System.out.println("Winner is " + gracze[j] + "\n");

                    for (int c = 0; c < gracze.length; c++) {

                        System.out.println("Number of try's " + gracze[c] + " equals " + liczbaProbGraczy[c]);

                    }

                    break;

                }

            }

        } while (los != guessingNumber);

        scan7.close();
        scan.close();
        scan2.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, there is no reason to open 3 different `Scanner`, you can use the same one for everything, there is 0 difference.

Comment: Thank you for input, I will test with 1 scanner only

Comment: `gracze.length` could theoretically be 0, the for-loop skipped and `guessingNumber` not asked. So must be inititalized here.

Comment: @Tomek Młynarski When you declare a variable inside a function(method) it doesn't get a default value and you must initialize it. If you declare a variable on a class level e.g. outside the function in your case it will get a default value when the instance is created. In your case for int it will get 0 if you defined it outside the function.

Comment: @Boris Borovski do you mean outside the main function?

Comment: @Tomek Młynarski Yes declare it static guessingNumber; outside the main function in your case.

Comment: @Boris Borovski your suggestion helped ! thank you

Comment: @Tomek Młynarski np

Comment: If your code (logic) depends on the value of `guessingNumber` in _any_ possible case (path) then naturally you'd want it to be set to something.  The compiler is saying in at least one case it may be uninitialized.  THis is an opportunity to review your logic as well - why are you depending on a value when it was not set.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare something to an uninitialized integer variable, you need to initialize it first. In your case you're trying to use the comparison while defining the integer inside of the same block that gets executed if the comparison is true.

Comment: If you declare Integer inside a method it cannot be un-initialized ... again e..g you say " integer can't be null because it's a primitive," and if it was object you say it will work ?

Comment: I was answering specifically what he was asking, if it's possible to use an uninitialized `int`.

Comment: It is in-possible to use uninitialized Integer also. Nvm :). If he use Integer guessingNumber; again the code will not compile.